# Netbean 12.0, how to generate class diagram and/or sequence diagram of package

Tags: netbeans, uml

I have not used Netbean for long time, maybe 10 years. Before I have used Netbean to generate UML diagram, for example class diagram and sequence diagram.

Now I use Netbean 12.0 for windows, OpenJDK 8. But I could not find the feature how to generate UML diagram. Any hints?

Comment: [esayUML](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55435/easyuml) plug-in seems working for Netbeans 11 so may be 12 too. But easyUML only supports class diagram. What about to use a UML modeler ?

Comment: @bruno Thanks for quick response. I have manually made classs diagram now. Now I try to a make sequency diagram. What kind of UML modeler do you recommend?

Comment: Being the author of [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) I am not sure to be the best placed to answer impartially ^^

Comment: @bruno Definately download to have a try! Br.